# Android AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator not working

Tags: android, android-animation

```
AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
set.playTogether(
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mCard, "scaleX", 1f, 0f),
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mCard, "scaleY", 1f, 0f),
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mBackground, "alpha", 1f, 0f)
);

set.setDuration(2000l);
set.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()); //this isn't working

set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);

        //Stuff here
    }

});

set.start();
```

This seems pretty straightforward to me, I've used interpolators in the past and have not had trouble. However, with this AnimatorSet, if I comment out the `setInterpolator` line the animation looks exactly the same. As you can see I slowed it down so I could make sure I wasn't just not noticing the effect, but it definitely isn't happening.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the default animation is `AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator`.  Looking at the Android sourcecode for `Animate`, the constructor does this:

```
public Animation() {
    ensureInterpolator();
}

protected void ensureInterpolator() {
    if (mInterpolator == null) {
        mInterpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();
    }
}
```

Try using a different interpolator to make sure it's working.